# In Flow Screen , Product2 lookup field is not populating for few users

Tags: visual-workflow, administration

In flow screen, we have a Product lookup field.
It's not working for few users while other users can access it(with different profile).

[image]

We provided necessary permissions to Product and it's related objects.
Now, when we debug the flow as the affected user (Run flow as another user check box checked) we are getting that particular product field.

[image]

Can you please share your thoughts why we are not getting the field? It would be a great help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked field-level security on the lookup field?

Comment: Yes , I checked that as well. Also at the debugging as user we are getting that field as well.